# How to restart Visual Studio manually?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

Is there any way to restart Visual Studio 2010 (and possibly 2008 as well but not so important) manually and keeping the current state (i.e. all open solutions/projects and files)? Basically the same operation as when you install an extension and Visual Studio asks to restart itself. Occasionally Visual Studio gets confused after things like folder renames/moves, reference changes or the GUI editor throws a wobbly so it would be nice to be able to quickly restart the solution/project rather than close Visual Studio, reopen it and load the solution/project again.

Comment: Have you gone through the list of installed extensions and tried disabling them? You really shouldn't need to keep restarting Visual Studio like that.

Comment: @Lasse - Sometimes I think it may be due to Resharper but I'm not going to remove that as it is too useful. I don't really know what causes these occasional hiccups and the restart usually resolves them.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I don't really like answering my own question but I found the [RestartStudio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f27f5495-3987-4e0f-8ce3-9a95efc05ce0) extension for Visual Studio 2010 that adds the restart option to the File menu and seems to work well.

Comment: Little things make life easier!

Comment: Sad that it's necessary.

Comment: does not install for VS2010

Comment: Doesn't work for VS2015 - "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products."

Comment: @noonand The question was specifically for VS2010, but if you want something for VS2015 then try: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RonDeFreitas.VisualStudioRestart2015

Comment: How to do this in express version of Visual Studio, I am in a situation where I need to restart VS in order for MvcMailer to Work.

Comment: As I remember, VS2010 Express doesn't work with extensions at all.

Comment: This should be the selected answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463497/7389293 even though it was done later in time, it is more complete.

Answer (score 22):

[Visual Studio Restart](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/01f0a1ae-1513-48dd-9cf0-efb38419b480) is another plugin that works for Visual Studio 2013.

[Restart Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarioHsiao.RestartVisualStudio) for 2015

[VSRestart2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-356819.VSRestart2017) for 2017

[Visual Studio Restart](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PaulMelia.VsRestart001) for 2017 & 2019

[Restart for Visual Studio 2022 Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pedoc.RestartVisualStudioforvs2022preview) for 2022

Comment: Doesn't work for VS2015 - "This extension is not installable on any currently installed products."

Comment: @noonand thanks for pointing that out, updated my answer with the available extensions for 2015 and 2017